# How to scale up distinct counts in MySQL? 25 million rows

Tags: mysql, performance, count, distinct

Is there a way to speed up this code? On 25 million rows, it took 22 hours to complete on a dedicated server.

On smaller tests of 1, 2, 3 and 4 million rows it took 13s, 26s, 1m15s and 5mins. I understand how it's an exponential time increase for additional rows as a distinct count has to search through all rows...

```
insert into Lookup_transactions (UCI, Transactions)
select    UCI,
            count(distinct transactions) as Transactions                         
from 18mths_summary
group by UCI;
```

UCI and transcations are both indexed. The table is an InnoDB.

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers,
Lucas

Comment: You probably hit a limit such as your amount of available RAM.

Comment: The server has 8gb of supposedly 'server grade' RAM. I'll check the RAM usage while it's running. Is there a more RAM efficient way to do this?

Comment: Also for distinct to be faster you want to create an index against that column. Then the distinct can be calculated very quickly. However, if everything fits in memory when you have up to 4M rows and not when you have 25M, that's your main culprit.

Comment: I've got indexes on the UCI and transactions columns. Is there a way to do this without using distinct? What would you do in this situation?

Comment: Hmmm... one way might be to create two other tables that assign numbers to UCI and Transactions if those are currently strings... then the SELECT would be faster, the result however would be the IDs instead of the actual string.